API project is not authorized to use this even no ristriction
I have a issue regarding
Directions API Response:
{
  "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
  "routes" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

this is error i always received from my Direction API whenever i tried calling to create rout between the origin and destination
for testing i used Log in android studio
(No routes found in the response.)
but this authorization issue always occurs.
I'm am using same API in Map SDK JavaScript & also using into Map SDK Android.
even while loading map on the android that key works. location markers update perfectly,
on Map SDK JavaScript with same api the routes working.
still the problem remains same in android studio.
in Android studio it places destination marker successfully but no route while creating the route.
Cross checked everything.
Enabling all api key
No ristriction
Generated new key's multiple times.
even created new project to generate new api. will anyone help me out.
Thanks & Regards
Stuck from last one Week.

This code for DirectionApi.java
public class DirectionsApi {
public static String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng destination, String apiKey) {
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
            "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude +
            "&destination=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude +
            "&mode=driving&key=" + apiKey;
    System.out.println("Directions API URL: " + url);
    return url;
}

public static String requestDirections(String url) throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static List<LatLng> parseDirectionsResponse(String response) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
    if (routes.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    JSONObject route = routes.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray legs = route.getJSONArray("legs");
    JSONObject leg = legs.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray steps = leg.getJSONArray("steps");

    List<LatLng> routeCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < steps.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject step = steps.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject polyline = step.getJSONObject("polyline");
        String polylineString = polyline.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = decodePolyline(polylineString);
        routeCoordinates.addAll(polylineCoordinates);
    }

    return routeCoordinates;
}

private static List<LatLng> decodePolyline(String polylineString) {
    List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;
    int lat = 0;
    int lng = 0;

    while (index < polylineString.length()) {
        int b;
        int shift = 0;
        int result = 0;

        do {
            b = polylineString.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);

        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;

        do {
            b = polylineString.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);

        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        polylineCoordinates.add(new LatLng(lat * 1e-5, lng * 1e-5));
    }

    return polylineCoordinates;
}

}

This is code of MapsActivity.java
private void getDirectionsToUser(LatLng userLatLng) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        // Show the progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                serviceProviderLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                String apiKey = getString(R.string.google_api_key); // Use the correct API key
                String url = DirectionsApi.getDirectionsUrl(serviceProviderLatLng, userLatLng, apiKey);

                executorService.execute(() -> {
                    try {
                        String result = DirectionsApi.requestDirections(url);
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            // Dismiss the progress dialog
                            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }

                            if (result != null) {
                                System.out.println("Directions API Response: " + result);
                                try {
                                    List<LatLng> routeCoordinates = DirectionsApi.parseDirectionsResponse(result);
                                    if (routeCoordinates != null && !routeCoordinates.isEmpty()) {
                                        addPolylinesToMap(routeCoordinates);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e("MapsActivity", "No routes found in the response.");
                                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "No routes found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse directions", e);
                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Failed to parse directions.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Failed to get directions.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch directions", e);
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Failed to get directions.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void addPolylinesToMap(final List<LatLng> routeCoordinates) {
        // Use a handler to run the code on the main thread
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            if (routeCoordinates != null && !routeCoordinates.isEmpty()) {
                Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(routeCoordinates));
                polyline.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MapsActivity.this, R.color.blue));
                polyline.setClickable(true);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "run: No routes found.");
            }
        });
    }

I want to create route between Origin and destination
Directions API Response: {   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",   "routes" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Generally (not familiar with Maps) this error message results when the Service or dependent Services are not enabled for the Project. You can enumerate the Project's services using gcloud services list --project=${PROJECT} or using Console (link). It is likely you will need to enable additional services (I don't know which ones you will need) from this list

Their is no restriction on the API keys I'm using but still it shows issue on logcat of
Directions API Response: {   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",   "routes" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
the service i wanna use is Direction API and want to draw a route using Direction API.

Please read my earlier comment. This likely isn't an issue with the API key but you must enable the service (API) in the Project in which you wish to use it.

My case Resolved, Anyone facing same It might be because your Android project is connected to Firebase. When calling an API for directions or displaying a map, it uses the Firebase API Key first. Here's solution:
A. Verify if Firebase is connected to your project and check the API.
B. Go to Google Console and find the project linked with Firebase (ensure  same Gmail account).
C. Select that project, go to Credentials -> Create Credentials -> Click on Help Me Choose. This will automatically create an API key. Cross-check with the Firebase API, enable your API, and check for any restrictions.
